# using ffmpeg to convert flac to alac with cover art

Tags: ffmpeg

I have seen a few discussions on this but none of them give the answer I was hoping for. I am trying to convert flac to alac while preserving all of the tags and the embedded cover image. I know we can manually set a cover image by passing a separate image file to ffmpeg.... but how do I use the one embedded in the flac file? dbpoweramp does this automatically, but I would rather use ffmpeg so that I can automate my workflow with a bash script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by adding a source that has a newer version...
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/ffmpeg-4`
...And using @logan command...
`ffmpeg -i input.flac -c:v copy -c:a alac output.m4a`

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
ffmpeg -i input.flac -c:v copy -c:a alac output.m4a
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that doesn't work for me

`
[ipod @ 0x55a0bbcecde0] Could not find tag for codec mjpeg in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:1 --
Conversion failed!
`

Comment: @Chris I'll need to see your command and the complete console output. You can use a pastebin site and provide a link in a comment.

Comment: Thats a good idea. Here is the link https://pastebin.com/x41mvWee

Comment: @Chris Your ffmpeg is too old. Download a new one [here](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/). Put it in `/usr/local/bin` (or `~/bin` but you'll have to log out/log in or run `source ~/.profile` for it to get recognized in `~/bin`).

Comment: I cant believe it was that simple. I would have thought the Ubuntu version would have been kept up to date. Never thought to even check. Lesson learned, thanks!

Comment: Maybe I spoke a little soon. Not all tags are preserved. Most are but some are not. This is what ffprobe has to say.... https://pastebin.com/MaY9pZRY

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get the jonathon ppa to work on my rig so you can use "`-vcodec copy` "
`"$FILE" -vcodec copy -acodec alac "$NEW_FILE"` to copy the image over to the new file.

However, I do see that file names with "()" sometimes don't convert. I don't get an error in my script it just moves on. without the copy. Would be nice if anyone know how to fix that.